# how would i go about opening the save as menu using python?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, saving

I'm trying to create an add-on that executes a few steps before opening the save as menu.
I am the point where I can execute the options and save the file, but I would like to open the save as menu, instead of directly saving over an already existing file.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False, 
properties=False)

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='X', 
orient_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, 
use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, 
use_proportional_projected=False)

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False, 
properties=False)

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-1.5708, orient_axis='X', 
orient_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False), mirror=True, 
use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, 
use_proportional_projected=False)

bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile()
bpy.context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

This is what I currently have, is there any way to instead of saving directly to the save_as_mainfile() , open the save as menu?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you've just unchecked the accepted answer?

Comment: No, didn't realize I unchecked it TBH, my apologies

Comment: No problem, I was just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to open the file browser you need the operator's `invoke()` function to be called. This can be accomplish by setting the [execution context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#execution-context). Pass the argument `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` into the function call and the file browser will open.

```
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#execution-context) explains the execution context in the following way:

> **Execution Context**
>
> When calling an operator you may want to pass the execution context.
>
> This determines the context that is given for the operator to run in, and whether `invoke()` is called or only `execute()`.
>
> ‘EXEC_DEFAULT’ is used by default, running only the `execute()` method, but you may want the operator to take user interaction with ‘INVOKE_DEFAULT’ which will also call `invoke()` if existing.
>
> [...]